# how to do if statement on the next item in list without list index out of range

Tags: python, list

Given a list, how do I go through it, and not do an operation if the next item in the list is empty?

Right now I have code below. But I get list index out of range error since the "`together[i+1]`" messes stuff up. Is there a way to get something like "`together[i+1]` unless `i == len(together)`"? in the same "if together[i+1] == """ line? Thank you for any help

```
for i, unit in enumerate(together):
        if together[i+1] == "":
             final.append(unit)
        else:
             if unit != "minutes":
                 unit += ", "
             else:
                 unit += " and "
             final.append(unit)
```

Comment: You can check `if i>=len(together)` to check if this is the last element of the array

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the list so that instead of looking ahead you determine what to do to the next one given the current one.

```
together.reverse()

skip = False

for unit in together:

    if(not skip):

        # If current entry is blank skip the next one
        if unit == "":
             skip = True

        else:
             # Current entry is not blank and the last entry is not blank
             # IDK if this is what you want to do in the loop or not, copied from your question
             if unit != "minutes":
                 unit += ", "
             else:
                 unit += " and "
             final.append(unit)

    else:
        skip = False

together.reverse()
```